# How to write the unit milli tesla meter?

Tags: siunitx

Right now I am using mTm (code: `\unit{10}{\milli\tesla\meter}`). I wanted the output to look like mT-m. The SIunits package documents talks about half-high dot but doesn't mention any hyphen. Any ideas?

Comment: With the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package you can easily do `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = {-}}`.

Comment: Is the hyphen allowed by SI rules?

Comment: Good point. Just that I have seen really good textbooks in engineering include the hyphen in their units. Right now I am using \usk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I wouldn't write it like that.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\mt{\milli\tesla} %% A method for say short cut or new unit!
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = {-}}

\begin{document}
\SI{40}{\mt\meter}

\SI{40}{\milli\tesla\meter}
\end{document}
```